# Printing multiple text strings from single cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm currently using Office 2003 to create a calendar with department codes relating to certain departments. Each "event" on the schedule has its own set of dept codes hidden next to each date, and I am trying to print the corresponding string (there can be multiple dept codes for each "event").  I need help to do this.

Summary

- The dept codes are in column D, starting at row 10 (i being the row variable).
- Each cell that contains these codes has letters separated by commas (ex [M, A, P]) - and I would like to be able to print multiple department names based on each of these department code cells)
- My intention for variable p is to find the place of each department code with the intention of using a vlookup.
- All of my department codes and text strings are found in P3:Q11, with column P including the department codes, and column Q including the corresponding department names/ text strings.
- p is set to increase by 3 times per loop, because I figured you would need to jump 3 characters to find the next possible department code (comma, space, new letter).
- I would like to print the solo/multiple text strings (depending on whether there is more than one dept code for the event) in the same row as the respective codes you are looking up are found, but in column K (as opposed to where the dept codes are located - column D)

---

```
Sub DepartmentNames()

Dim i As Long

Dim p As Integer

Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 10 To LastRow

    For p = 1 To Len("D" & i) Step 3

        ' Placeholder

    Next

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my proposed solution, using the Split function and a collection.

```
Sub Reference()

' Disable screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wS As Worksheet
Set wS = ActiveSheet   ' you can change it to be a specific sheet

Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


Dim Dpts As Variant
Dim dFullText As Variant
Dim LookUp As New Collection

' Create a collection where the key is the shortcode and the value is the full name of the dpt
On Error Resume Next
For i = 3 To 11

    LookUp.Add wS.Cells(i, 17), wS.Cells(i, 16)

Next i
On Error GoTo 0


' Loop on each row
For i = 10 To LastRow

    Dpts = Split(wS.Cells(i, 4), ",") ' Split creates an array

    ' First case
    dFullText = LookUp.Item(Trim(Dpts(0)))   ' TRIM = remove trailing and leading spaces

    ' The rest of them
    For j = 1 To UBound(Dpts)

        dFullText = dFullText & ", " & LookUp.Item(Trim(Dpts(j)))

    Next j

    ' Put full text in column K
    wS.Cells(i, 11).Value = dFullText

Next i

' Enable screen updating again
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Let me know if you need clarification

Comment: Obviously, You'll see that I used On Error Resume Next and then On Error Goto 0 to loop between 3 and 11 (P3:Q11). That was because the code would crash if ever you had a blank value in there (and I didn't want to populate all of those line to test it)... Needless to say that it would be better to dynamically determine the size of your lookup table. That you seem to already know how to do! (Currentregion, or End(xlUp) for example)

Comment: Thanks for your help Julien. When I run the code I am getting a compile error: type mismatch with the Sub Reference () line being challenged. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I take that back, I got it to work. I just have one more question-

Would it be possible to produce All Depts if all department codes are located in column C? Currently the first code for all of them is the master code (meaning all departments), and I would either like to

A) Make that code only appear if all of the other department codes are present or

B) Not appear at all

Thanks again Julien!

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly. You mean if you have all the departments letter in column D then print "All Dpts" in column K instead of the list of all departments? If yes, then just add an If statement. I assume your number of department isn't likely to change everyday so you can just test the length of the string between For i = 10 to Last row and the split function. If len(ws.cells(i,4) = X then dFulltext = "All Dpts" Else... If that answer above solved it, mark it as such please!

Comment: Sorry! Maybe this will be more clear-

On a per line basis, if a cell for an event contains all of the dept codes (ex M, A, P, G, etc) then I want it to produce All in that row's column K instead of individually listing the name of each department in that row's column K

Comment: So that's exactly what I described just before. Test the length of the String. If it is 25, then you have all dpts. Otherwise, split the array etc. Solved?

Comment: Actually, better yet, I usually don't trust people to be very very rigorous and put spaces after the coma. Do the split and test the number of items in the array. If it is equal to the numbers of dpts (9 in your case I believe) then write ws.cells(i,11) = "All Dpts"